# Extracting elements from a chisq output in R

Tags: r, dplyr, chi-squared

```
library(survey)
```

I am using the survey package to produce the P value and Chisq between two of the categorical variables. I would like to run the chisquare on many variables at once and extract the data into a data frame.

I have data such as this.

```
df <- data.frame(sex = c('F', 'M', NA, 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F'),
                     happy = c('Y', 'Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','N'),
                     married = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                     pens = c(0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                     weight = c(1.12, 0.55, 1.1, 0.6, 0.23, 0.23, 0.66, 0.67))
```

I run the following code to create the survey design:

```
design <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~weight)
```

To find the chi squared of sex and pens:

```
svychisq(~sex+pens, design, statistic = "Chisq")

    Pearson's X^2: Rao & Scott adjustment

data:  svychisq(~sex + pens, design, statistic = "Chisq")
X-squared = 8, df = 1, p-value = 1.319e-08
```

My actual dataset is very large, and I want to find the chisq of many variables (in this case, sex and happy) and get the output into a neat df like this:

```
Question  Group    Chisq  Pval
sex       pens     78     0.001
sex       married  45     0.100
happy     pens     34     0.3
happy     married  87     2.0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
vector_vars <- c("sex", "happy") 
myfun <- function(x){
  form <- reformulate(sprintf('interaction(%s)', x))
  all <- as.data.frame(svychisq(form + pens, design, statistic = "Chisq"))
  stat <- all$statistic # get the chi sq val
  p <- all$p.value  # get the p val
  cbind(as.data.frame(stat,p))
}


out_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vector_vars, myfun))
```

I get this error:

```
  Error in terms(formula) : object 'pens' not found
```

I don't think I am extracting the elements correctly. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the same formula as in the  `svychisq(~sex+pens, design, statistic = "Chisq")`

Comment: @akrun yes.. that is the formula I am trying to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reformulate` in the function can be changed by specifying the `termlabels` as a vector of 'pens' with the looped variable name, then pass that formula into `svychisq`, use `tidy` to convert the output to a `tibble` and `rbind` the `list` of `tibble`s to a single `tibble`

```
myfun <- function(x){
 form <- reformulate(termlabels = c('pens', x))
 all <- broom::tidy(svychisq(form, design, statistic = "Chisq")) %>% 
           dplyr::mutate(var_name = x, .before = 1)
 
}

purrr::map_dfr(vector_vars, myfun)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  var_name statistic      p.value parameter method                               
#  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>     <int> <chr>                                
#1 sex          8.    0.0000000132         1 Pearson's X^2: Rao & Scott adjustment
#2 happy        0.880 0.383                1 Pearson's X^2: Rao & Scott adjustment
```

Comment: this is perfect!! Is there a way to add the variable name in this?

Comment: @NewBee yes, added that

Answer (score 1):

With base R you could do:

```r
out_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vector_vars, 
    function(x){with(svychisq(reformulate(termlabels = c('pens', x)),
        design, statistic = "Chisq"), 
        data.frame(stat=statistic, p=p.value, row.names = x))}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `svychisq`to an object.
then check `names()`
and with `test$p.value` get the p.value or choose from names whatever you need
In your case `test$statistic`

```
test <- svychisq(~sex+pens, design, statistic = "Chisq")
names(test)
#test$p.value
test$statistic

# Output:
> test <- svychisq(~sex+pens, design, statistic = "Chisq")
> names(test)
[1] "statistic" "parameter" "p.value"   "method"    "data.name" "observed"  "expected"  "residuals" "stdres"   
> test$p.value
   X-squared 
1.319262e-08 

> test$statistic
X-squared 
        8
```